# How to iterate through an array of objects from json in React.js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, loops, object

I am trying to loop through an array of objects in an external json file using the map function.  The loop succeeds but I am not sure how to access the object properties. See below.

I am using object.keys(obj).map() but cannot get access to the individual properties.  Map keeps outputting the array index numbers.

This is my data I want to iterate through.

```
[
   {
     "id" : "12345",
     "customer" : "BMW",
   },
   {
     "id" : "45678",
     "customer" : "Ford",
   },
   {
     "id" : "78901",
     "customer" : "Google",
   } 
]
```

I have a state hook that the data will be saved to

```
const [accountData, setAccountData] = useState('');
```

The function below gets the data from the external json file and sets the state with it.

```
 axios.get('./data/account-info.json')
  .then((response) => {
     //set state
     setAccountData(response.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
     console.log(error);
  });
```

I iterate through the state object with a map function

```
Object.keys(accountData).map((id,customer) => {
  return(
    <div>
      <p>ID: {id}</p>
      <p>Name: {customer}</p>
    </div>
  )
})
```

The output keeps printing out the index numbers instead of the appropriate values

```
//outputted elements

<div>
  <p>ID: 0</p>
  <p>Name: 0</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>ID: 1</p>
  <p>Name: 1</p>
</div>

<div>
  <p>ID: 2</p>
  <p>Name: 2</p>
</div>
```

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong here? I know it has to be something simple.

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate `accountData` directly, as it's an array.
Each item will be an object, so you need to [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) as you see below.
(*you don't need to but that's was the intention I perceived from your code*)

And also you need to add a key to each element, to notify React how to keep track of elements.

```
//                destrcuture the properties
accountData.map(({ id,customer }) => {
  return(
   {/*  make sure to add keys here too */}
    <div key={id}>
      <p>ID: {id}</p>
      <p>Name: {customer}</p>
    </div>
  )
})
```

**-- Reply to the [COMMENT] --**

> so whenever I remove the object.keys() it throws this error at me TypeError: accountData.map is not a function

Would you double check if `response.data` is as what you mentioned in the post?
If you run the code below, it will correctly print `id` & `customer` array.

```js
let accountData = [
   {
     "id" : "12345",
     "customer" : "BMW",
   },
   {
     "id" : "45678",
     "customer" : "Ford",
   },
   {
     "id" : "78901",
     "customer" : "Google",
   } 
] 
accountData.map(({id, customer}) => console.log(id, customer))
```

Comment: so whenever I remove the object.keys() it throws this error at me ```TypeError: accountData.map is not a function```

Comment: @DavidSanders I've updated the answer. `accountData.map` should work, if the data you mentioned in the question is what is being returned

Answer (score 2):

try this

Object.keys(accountData).map((e) => {
  return(

ID: {e.id}

Name: {e.customer}

)
})

Answer (score 0):

`Object.keys(accountData)` will give you the keys of the array, ex 0,1,2. just do `accountData.map` to iterate through the array instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
accountData.map(customer => {
  return(
    <div
      key={ customer.id }
     >
      <p>ID: { customer.id }</p>
      <p>Name: { customer.customer }</p>
    </div>
  )
})
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that using the `index` of a map function to define the `key` is an anti-pattern in react. https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: Right you are. Suppose that id is unique. Code has been refactored.

Answer (score 0):

Object.keys function returns the array of its keys. For array object, its keys are its indices. So in case of your accountData, Object.keys(accountData) returns [ '0', '1', '2' ].

If you still want to use Object.keys function, you can do like this.

```
Object.keys(accountData).map(key => (
    <div key={accountData[key].id}>
        <p>ID: {accountData[key].id}</p>
        <p>Name: {accountData[key].customer}</p>
    </div>
));
```

But in case of an array, it would be better to apply map function directly to it.

```
accountData.map(account => (
    <div key={account.id}>
        <p>ID: {account.id}</p>
        <p>Name: {account.customer}</p>
    </div>
));
```

That's all.